# Margin doesn't work on a side without any constraint in ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I have an ImageView in a ConstraintLayout whose id is "thumbnail" in the XML below. I want it to be aligned top left of its parent and have a 8dp margin at bottom. However, bottom margin is not applied since there is no constraint on that side. I don't connect its bottom to its parent because it gets centered, which I don't want.

Is there any way to solve this? Like to be able align it to the top when bottom constraint is provided?

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_width="56dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/bg_track_artwork" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin"
        android:text="Title"
        android:textColor="#040404"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="sans"
        app:firstBaselineToTopHeight="32dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/subtitle"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/itemMenu"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/thumbnail"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/subtitle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Subtitle"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        app:firstBaselineToTopHeight="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/title"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/title"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/title" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/itemMenu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/quarter_margin"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/title"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
            android:id="@+id/overflowIcon"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/icon_width"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/icon_height"
            android:padding="@dimen/icon_padding"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_more"
            app:tint="@color/icon_gray_light" />

    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Constraining the ImageView to the bottom of the parent as well as the top of the parent will center the widget top-to-bottom *if* the vertical bias is 0.5, the default value. If the vertical bias is set to 0, then the widget will nestle against the top of the ConstraintLayout regardless of how tall it gets and will maintain its bottom margin when the layout collapses.

Add the following to the XML for *thumbnail*:

```
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0"
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use bottom padding on parent ConstraintLayout instead of bottom margin on ImageView. That is the easiest solution I find.

There is one more solution which I use in these situations. I manually set constraint bottom with bottom margin on child view, when I know that the parent constraint layout will shrink.

You can add new constraints programmatically by doing the following

`val constraintSet = ConstraintSet()
            constraintSet.clone(constraintLayout)
            constraintSet.connect(R.id.thumbnail, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, 8)
            constraintSet.applyTo(constraintLayout)`

Comment: That's what I do for now actually, but wondered if there is a way without modifying the parent view.

Comment: I updated my response. If you need more details how I am adding constraints programmatically, just ask.

Comment: Please share. If I define a constraint for bottom of "thumbnail" and if the title and subtitle are multiple lines, the parent's height is bigger than "thumbnail" and the "thumbnail" is centered vertically.

Comment: Hmm that's a bit tricky, because if you want to set constraints manually, you will have to know when your title and subtitle are multiple lines.